# g++: fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but liblto_plugin-0.dll not found

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw

i am the beginner of mingw. pls answer my question some expert. I did the following processes:

- i have installed mingw-get-setup.exe for C++ compiler
- i have also used Eclipse-cpp-europa-winter-win32 for C++ IDE
- i have also used the following uer environmental variables:
- "<"installation-directory">"\bin;
- "<"installation-directory">"\MSYS\1.0\local\bin;
- "<"installation-directory">"\MSYS\1.0\bin

But i have "launch failed no binaries" error when i run my program. I have built the program before run. I have also get the following error in console:

- Build of configuration Debug for project test ****
- Internal Builder is used for build**               ****
- g++ -otest.exe test.o
- **g++: fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but liblto_plugin-0.dll not
  found**
- compilation terminated.
- Build error occurred, build is stopped
- Time consumed: 78  ms.**

Answer (score 0):

You must add `C:\MinGW\bin;` to your user PATH environment variable manually. You can permanently add `C:\MinGW\bin;` to your PATH by following the instructions in the "Environment Settings" section on the MinGW [Getting Started](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started) page.

Source [here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/InstallationHOWTOforMinGW).

Answer (score 0):

Check PATH environment variable and look for a path to another MinGW installation. I have two MinGW installed (first one in Falcon C++ IDE directory), and second one I installed by myself. There was two paths to MinGW in system PATH environment variable and that caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

What I encountered is: when installing MingW32, by default, it only install "gcc". So in the system, g++ is still the GNU version, so it cannot find MingW32 liblto_plugin-0.dll.
I guess the g++ running in your environment is not the one you intend to use.

```
$ which gcc
/MinGW/bin/gcc

$ which g++
/usr/bin/g++

$ gcc --version
gcc.exe (MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-5) 8.2.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ g++ --version
g++.exe (GCC) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```